# Filling between more than two boundaries

Tags: plotting, filling, constraint

Here is a simple example of what I am trying to do; fill the area described by the three inequalities:

$$ y \le 11 + x    \label{1}      \tag{1}$$
  $$ y \le 27 - x               \tag{2}$$
  $$ y \le \frac{1}{5}(90 - 2x) \tag{3}$$

I have so far:

```
Plot[{11 + x, 27 - x, 1/5 (90 - 2 x)}, {x, 0, 20}, 
    Filling -> {2 -> {{3}, {White, LightBlue}}}]
```

Which produces:

[image]

My question is how to add multiple constraints on an area in general -- so for this specific question add the constraint specified by equation $\eqref{1}$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: You could use your constraints to define a `Region` and then use `RegionPlot` to plot it, including a colored fill.  Search this website for similar questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
r = ImplicitRegion[
   y <= 11 + x && y <= 27 - x && y <= 1/5 (90 - 2 x) && x >= 0 && 
    y >= 0, {x, y}];
Show[Plot[{11 + x, 27 - x, 1/5 (90 - 2 x)}, {x, 0, 20}, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}], RegionPlot[r]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

```
Plot[{11 + x, 27 - x, 1/5 (90 - 2 x), Min[11 + x, 27 - x], 
  Min[11 + x, 27 - x, 1/5 (90 - 2 x)]}, {x, 0, 20}, 
 Filling -> {5 -> {Axis, {White, LightBlue}}, 4 -> {{3}, {None, Yellow}}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Depend on @kglr, but only use three functions.

```
Plot[{11 + x, 27 - x, 1/5 (90 - 2 x)}, {x, 0, 20}, PlotPoints -> 40, 
 Filling -> {3 -> {Axis, {None, Blue}}, 2 -> {{3}, {White, None}}, 
   1 -> {{3}, {White, None}}}]
```

[image]

Comment: `Plot[{Min[11 + x, 27 - x, 1/5 (90 - 2 x)], 11 + x, 27 - x, 
  1/5 (90 - 2 x)}, {x, 0, 20}, Filling -> {1 -> {Axis, Blue}}, 
 Exclusions -> None]`