# Filling between more than two boundaries broken?

Tags: plotting, filling

I want to fill between several curves. The documentation suggests

```
Filling->{1->{{3},{None, Automatic}}, 2->{{3},{None, Automatic}}}
```

should do the trick. But it leads to the error

Filling::invfillentry: {2->{{3},{None,Automatic}},2->{{3},{None,Automatic}}} is not a valid Filling specification. >>

Indeed,

```
Filling->{2->{{3},{None, Automatic}}}
```

Yields the same error.

An earlier post: [Filling between more than two boundaries](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78791/125) included the example:

```
Plot[{11 + x, 27 - x, 1/5 (90 - 2 x), Min[11 + x, 27 - x], 
Min[11 + x, 27 - x, 1/5 (90 - 2 x)]}, {x, 0, 20}, 
Filling -> {5 -> {Axis, {White, LightBlue}}, 4 -> {{3}, {None, Yellow}}}]
```

That returns the error

Filling::invfillentry: {4->{{3},{None,Yellow}},4->{{3},{None,Yellow}},4->{{3},{None,Yellow}},4->{{3},{None,Yellow}}} is not a valid Filling specification. >>

Did this filling spec get broken at some point? I'm using Mathematica 10.0.2.0.

Comment: The code above works fine on macOS with MMA V12.1. I can't comment specifically on your version, but it does seem weird that the error returns the same specification over and over rather than the list you show. Have you tried restarting the kernel?

Answer (score 2):

Your code works fine for me (v. 11.3):

[image]